# How can I order the results of several async JQuery queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pulling in information from several web services to display on a web page. I'd like to be able to order the results, but keep the fetching dynamic. However, the way I've structured the code means that the elements get inserted into the DOM in the order that the requests complete, which is non-deterministic. How can I guarantee a specific order, but avoid inserting 'dud' elements if one of the results errors out instead of returning valid info?

```
// Get my apps from iTunes
var iTunesLinks = ["525393529", "645218452", "737479996"];
var iTunesSquareSize = 128;

$.each(iTunesLinks, function(index, value) {

    var iTunesLink = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=" + value + "&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(iTunesLink, function(data) {

       var items = [];
       items.push("<section id=\"myApps\"><table>");

       var results = data.results;

       $.each ( results, function( key, val ) {

            var appName = val.trackName;
            var iconURL = val.artworkUrl100;
            var appURL = val.trackViewUrl;
            items.push( "<td align=center width=" + iTunesSquareSize + " style=\"vertical-align:top\">" + divStart + "<a href=" + appURL + " target=_blank><img src=\"" + iconURL + "\" width=" + iTunesSquareSize + " height=" + iTunesSquareSize + "></a></div><a href=" + appURL + " target=_blank>" + appName + "</a></td>" );     
       });

       items.push("</table></section>");

       $( "<td/>", {
         "class": "applist",
         html: items.join( "" )
       }).appendTo( document.getElementById("myApps") );
    });
});
```

Comment: If you collect the returned promises into an array or promises and then pass that to `$.when()`, it will keep them all in order for you when `$.when()` is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for turning me onto $.when. I would +1 you if you make it an answer.

Comment: @rontornambe - answer added that shows how to use `$.when()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use collect all the promises into an array, pass that to [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and then when that is resolved, you will have all the data from all the async ajax calls in order like this:

```
// Get my apps from iTunes
var iTunesLinks = ["525393529", "645218452", "737479996"];
var iTunesSquareSize = 128;
var promises = [];

$.each(iTunesLinks, function(index, value) {

    var iTunesLink = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=" + value + "&callback=?";
    promises.push($.getJSON(iTunesLink));

});

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(/* arg1Array, arg2Array, arg3Array, ... */) {
    // now process all the results in order
    var items, results;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        // arguments[i] is an array of [data, statusText, jqXHR]
        results = arguments[i][0].results;
        items = [];
        items.push("<section id=\"myApps\"><table>");

        $.each ( results, function( key, val ) {

            var appName = val.trackName;
            var iconURL = val.artworkUrl100;
            var appURL = val.trackViewUrl;
            items.push( "<td align=center width=" + iTunesSquareSize + " style=\"vertical-align:top\">" + divStart + "<a href=" + appURL + " target=_blank><img src=\"" + iconURL + "\" width=" + iTunesSquareSize + " height=" + iTunesSquareSize + "></a></div><a href=" + appURL + " target=_blank>" + appName + "</a></td>" );     
        });

        items.push("</table></section>");

        $( "<td/>", {
         "class": "applist",
         html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo( document.getElementById("myApps") );
    }
});
```